# Why do I have to specify the type for each item at the initialization of std::array<SomeStruct, size> in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, stdarray, list-initialization

Given the SomeStruct as below:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    int i;
    char c;
};
```

Below does not compile.

```
int main() {
    std::array<SomeStruct,2> arr = {{3, 't'}, {3, 't'}}; 
}
```

But the code below works.

```
int main() {
    std::array<SomeStruct,2> arr = {SomeStruct{3, 't'}, SomeStruct{3, 't'}}; 
}
```

And this one works as well:

```
int main() {
    std::array<SomeStruct,1> arr = {{3, 't'}}; 
}
```

Why does this `std::array<SomeStruct,2> arr = {{3, 't'}, {3, 't'}};` cause a compilation error?

Plus, is there a more concise way to put `std::array<SomeStruct,2> arr = {SomeStruct{3, 't'}, SomeStruct{3, 't'}}`?
I don't want to use `arr.fill(SomeStruct{3,'t'})` or a loop. I want to set all the items to the same `SomeStruct{3, 't'}` at initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if a `std::array` initialization doesn't seem to work, keep adding extra pairs of braces until it does...

```
std::array<SomeStruct,2> arr = {{{3, 't'}, {3, 't'}}};
```

The reasons behind this and the history are long and complicated, it boils down to contention between aggregate initialization (a wart from C compatibility) and non-aggregate list initialization (added in C++11).